# How can I verify if a Windows Service is running

Tags: c#, windows-services, watchdog

I have an application in C# (2.0 running on XP embedded) that is communicating with a 'watchdog' that is implemented as a Windows Service. When the device boots, this service typically takes some time to start. I'd like to check, from my code, if the service is running. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please have a look on the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(VS.80).aspx) object in .NET.

Comment: Oooh...even better than rolling your own via WMI. I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @EBGreen - I don't know, the WMI route may be useful for someone else in future, there's more than one way to skin a cat, and all that....

Comment: Ya, but I really do think ServiceController is better over all, so I think I will leave it deleted. I never would have even suggested WMI if I hadn't just woken up. :)

Answer (score 415, accepted):

I guess something like this would work:

Add `System.ServiceProcess` to your project references (It's on the .NET tab).

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);

switch (sc.Status)
{
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
        return "Running";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
        return "Stopped";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
        return "Paused";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
        return "Stopping";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
        return "Starting";
    default:
        return "Status Changing";
}
```

Edit: There is also a method `sc.WaitforStatus()` that takes a desired status and a timeout, never used it but it may suit your needs.

Edit: Once you get the status, to get the status again you will need to call `sc.Refresh()` first.

Reference: [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(VS.80).aspx) object in .NET.

Comment: ServiceController.GetServices() retrieves a array that contains all the installed service as ServiceController object. This may help a lot.

Comment: Good call, I don't know if I've ever used that. Even if you never use it, I guess that it would be useful for debugging if nothing else

Comment: Add reference to System.ServiceProcess and add the statement:
using System.ServiceProcess;

Comment: If I passed a bad service name, it seemed to lock up instead of throwing an error.  I added this code: 
 
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return "Not found"; 
            }

Comment: NealWalters: How do you know the exception was thrown just because the service was not found? Isn't there a more suitable exception type to catch?

Comment: private static bool ServiceExists(string serviceName)
        {
            return ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == serviceName) != null;
        }

Comment: By the way `SERVICENAME` would be equal to the `ServiceName` property on the installer used for the service. If it matches your project name, an easy shortcut is to just use `this.ServiceName`

Comment: What's has more performance: new ServiceController(svcName) or ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault ?

Comment: and you need to add a reference to this assembly: ServiceProcess

Comment: I found that I had to add more generic exception catches for when services did not exist.

Comment: I've rolled back the changes that were made to this answer, because it should have been a new answer, rather than a full replacement for an existing answer with 300 votes.

Comment: So .NET 5 has made this more difficult with a System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'ServiceController enables manipulating and accessing Windows services and it is not applicable for other operating systems.'  Any suggestions?

Comment: For .NET Core you need the NuGet package `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`, and it will only work on Windows.

Answer (score 21):

Here you get all available services and their status in your local machine.

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
foreach(ServiceController service in services)
{
    Console.WriteLine(service.ServiceName+"=="+ service.Status);
}
```

You can Compare your service with service.name property inside loop and you get status of your service.
For details go with the  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx
also  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.servicemanager(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: This has a weak performance because you would have to loop over each and every service that's currently installed on the system in search for a single service. I recommend using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/178162/5262734