# Windows services

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, monitoring

I have a windows application and I need to change it into a windows service, How can I check whether the windows service is running or not without using any external service to keep a check on the main service.

Is there any way to check it within the main service as I have tried work on it but if the windows service is stopped then there is no way I can check on it.

Do I have to implement the thread(keep alive thread) for this, if so then how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

If your main service is not running, how can it check anything?

You *have* to have a second monitoring service of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at

- [How can I verify if a Windows
  Service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running)
- [Detect the Status of a Windows
  Service](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DetectServiceStatus.aspx)

Comment: And this is also implemented _externally_ to the monitored service.