# Check if SQL Server Agent is running from code?

Tags: sql-server, smo

How can I determine from code, if SQL Server Agent is running - using SMO?

I would think there was a property on the JobServer class, but I can't find anything.

Powershell is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if windows service (SQL Server Agent) is running...

Comment: Of course! Found the code for doing that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running