# Check to see if "Server" service is running - Multilingual C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I need to check and see if the "Server" service is running. Easy enough, using a method like this: [How can I verify if a Windows Service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running)

The problem comes in when the OS installation is not English. For example on a Windows installation, the "Server" service is known as "Serveur". Obviously I don't want to hardcode separate languages into my app. Anyone have any good ideas for doing this cleanly?

Comment: Wont the _actual_ service name always be `LanmanServer`? Where `Server`, or `Serveur`, is the display name.

Comment: Have you tried the method in that answer, or are you assuming it won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test out the following code and see what results you get, you may be surprised...

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

var controller = new ServiceController("LanmanServer");

Console.WriteLine(controller.ServiceName); // <- this is the unique name

Console.WriteLine(controller.DisplayName); // <- this is subject to change
```

Comment: Yes this was exactly it. I should have released that before I posted!

Answer (score 1):

Like the others, I suspect that the service name doesn't change across languages. It's usually the display name that changes.