# Is it possible to verify if a Windows Service is running from a different computer?

Tags: c#, process, windows-services, remote-access

I'm working on a project that is composed of a few windows services that collect data and persist them into a database. Now I have to develop an administration panel (a windows application) that can  show the statuses of windows services to user. I found out how to verify if a windows service is running using C#: [How can I verify if a Windows Service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running)

But my problem is: my windows services are running on a server and the user will run the administration panel on his/her computer. Is it possible to detect the status of a windows service from another computer. If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with WMI, [this example](http://www.go4coding.com/post/2011/02/22/Stop-service-running-on-remote-computer-using-WMI-in-C-Sharp.aspx) works for me (Obviously comment out the Stop part)

Comment: Thanks Alex. It seems good, but there is a point that I didn't understand. ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + ipAddress + @"\root\cimv2"); In that line do I have to change the @"\root\cimv2" part?

Comment: No, you just change the `ipAddress` to that of the machine running the services you wish to examine

Answer (score 0):

Not a C# developer, but logically speaking, I would make a small background application which checks these services on the server, and then I talk to this application and request the status of any of my services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pslist command: It gives you information about the running processes on a remote computer, however you have to provide credentials to access the other computer...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682