# Stop windows service if running before run again from installer c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

i have created installer for windows service and from `AfterInstall` event i am starting service but before start the service i like to check if service is not running then i will start the service otherwise not but i do not know how to check my service is running or not from `AfterInstall` event. please guide. thanks

```
using System.ServiceProcess;  
class ServInstaller : ServiceInstaller
{
    void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
        {
            sc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I verify if a Windows Service is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running)

Comment: Have a look at the link, it shows you how to check if it's running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it as shown below :-

```
using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
{    
   if  ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||
     (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
   {
   // Your code when service stopped
   }  
}
```