# How to check if Quartz.Net service on serve is started or not

Tags: c#

I have a Quartz job which in scheduled on server(clients server). I need to check if Quartz service is running or not ? If it is paused or something I need to send email notification to client that server is not started yet.

Comment: I think quartz uses a windows service. So, you can check it in the task manager / services. Also, you can check too in control panel / administrative tools / services. In both you can see if it is executing or not and his initialization type

Comment: I want to check it by my c# code

Comment: See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running