# net core 2.0 check if service is running

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-core-2.0

I am doing a `C# Net Core 2.0 Application`. I need to execute a `Windows Service`, but before I need to check if it is running.

I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running) post that the best way is using `ServiceController` like this

```
try
{
    using( ServiceController sc = new ServiceController( SERVICE_NAME ) )
    {
        return sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;
    }
}
```

But I do not find it in `Net core 2.0`

How can I checked it ?

Comment: Almost all "extra" libraries are added via Nuget in .NET Core.  If you bothered to google this you would see.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are new in Net Core 2.0.. 
here is the answer..

In `Nuget Console Mode`... write

```
PM>  Install-Package System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController -Version 4.4.1
```