# How to finish code execution after stopping windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm using a simple windows service app. Some of the code takes around a minute to finish executing. If I want to rollout news changes to production, how do I ensure that even after I stopped the service, the service finished what ever it's executing?

Comment: Your code to finish up should be in the `OnStop` method in the `ServiceBase` derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new service would need to check to make sure the old process isn't running.

[How can I verify if a Windows Service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running)

A better way would be to fix your service so it can be shutdown in a reasonable length of time. A minute is much too long to stop a service.

Whatever it's doing needs to be able to cleanly stop or roll back on request.